# Calculation averages per patient using n_distinct with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, average, distinct-values

In my dataframe I would like to calculate the absolute frequencies of performed healthcare activities, the relative frequency and the average number performed per patient.

I used the following code to calculate healthcare utilization:

```
Df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   summarize(n = n()) %>%
   mutate(rel.freq = (n/sum(n))*100) %>%
   mutate(avg.A.pt = n/sum(n_distinct(Person[A == A])))
```

I have a problem with the last line of the code.
I need to calculate the number of activities per patient for one specific type of care, calculated as total number of the activity `n` divided by the unique number of patients `n_distinct(Person)`, but only divided by the patients that recived that specific type of care `Person[HCU == HCU]`.

The results I am aiming for would look like this:

```
*HCU    n     rel.freq     avg.hcu.pt*
ECG   486      10%          4.0
Echo  301      8%           1.8
```

Could you help me fix the code?

Thank you in advance!

---

After a reply, some extra information:

I work with remote access in a secured environment, so unfortunately I'm not able to provide you with samples of the data.
I have a dataset of approximately 20.000 patients who received 11.000.000 healthcare activities (rows) and 34 columns with for example the specialism, healthcare centre, age and a personal code.
For my article I would like to show:
-    a percentage of (unique) patients who received a specific healthcare activity at least once (I called it the relative frequency)
-   Average number of the healthcare activity (of a specific type) per (unique) patient

Basically I have mapped the types of care, for example lab test using group_by and filter of dplyr, this gave me the total number of lab tests. 
But now I want to specify it, for example how many patients had at least one MRI, how many never had an MRI, how many MRI’s (on average) did the patients receive.

I tried your suggestion

```
Df %>%
Group_by(A, Person) %>%
Summarise(n = n())

# A= healthcare activities
```

Which gives me:

```
A            Person         n
MRI        1                 6
MRI        2                 2
… for all >1000 patients who received MRI
Echo      1                 3
And so on
```

How do I get the % of patients with MRI? And the average number of MRI’s per patient?

Comment: A reproducible data frame would help us to find the issue. One issue is that "Person" is not available after grouping by "A" and then making one summary value "n". Perhaps you want to group by Person and A? then summarise n=n() gives number of health care activities pr. person. You can summarize again to get the total activities for all persons.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I added some text in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets create some toy data. Four treatments with different probabilities.
100 patients visit 1000 times.

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(A = sample(c("MRI", "ECG", "Echo", "PET"), 1000,
                          prob=c(0.05, 0.8, 0.13, 0.02), replace=TRUE),
               p = sample(1:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

Now we aggregate the data

```
    df %>% 
  # group by Treatment and patients
  group_by(A, p) %>% 
  # first summary is the number of a specific treatments for each patient
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  # next summary we sum the number distinct patients in the group
  # and divide by sum the number of distinct patients to get the rel.freq of the treatment.
  # Then we take the mean value of the number of treatment pr. patient 
  summarise(rel.freq   = n_distinct(p)/n_distinct(df$p),
            avg.hcu.pt = mean(n))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
A     rel.freq avg.hcu.pt
<fct>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 ECG       1          8.02
2 Echo      0.76       1.72
3 MRI       0.37       1.30
4 PET       0.17       1.12
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!